# OpenGL multithreaded scene graph traversal

Tags: multithreading, opengl

I am seeking to improve the performance by reduce scene graph traversal overhead before each render call.I am not very experienced with multi-threaded software design so after reading a [couple](http://blog.slapware.eu/game-engine/programming/multithreaded-renderloop-part2/) of articles regarding multi-threaded rendering I am unsure how to approach this issue:

My rendering engine is completely deterministic and renders frames based on incoming transformation instructions in sequential manner at each new frame.I currently see the threaded scene graph update routine as something like this:

--------------CPU-------------------------------------|------GPU--------|----Frame Number----|

Update Frame 0 Transforms (spawn thread) |             GL RenderCall  |           Frame 0

Update Frame 1 Transforms (spawn thread) |             GL RenderCall  |           Frame 1

Update Frame 2 Transforms (spawn thread) |             GL RenderCall  |           Frame 2

...
.......

...............

Before the  first draw call I start updating first(Frame 1) frame in separate tread and proceed with render call.At the end of that call I start new thread for update of frame 2 ,check if the thread for frame one is done and if true , I call next render call.And so on and so on. 
That is how I see this happening.I have 2 questions:

1.Is it the proper (simple) way to design this kind of system?

2.What is the likelihood of render loop stalls because the scene graph update thread hasn't finished the update in synch with the start of the next render call?

I know some of the people here will say it depends on  specific scene graph tree complexity, but I would like to know how it usually goes in reality and what are the major drawbacks of such a design/

Comment: People say that it depends on the complexity because it really does depend on the complexity. There is no "usual" case, because there's too many things that it depends on. If you try to update a huge, complex scene, then you're more likely to have to wait for it to finish updating before you can draw. However, it will (almost) always be faster than simply using a single-threaded approach, so I'd say that it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Yeah I see , it makes sense ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, you shouldn't render to a common OpenGL drawable from multiple threads, as this would result in a net slowdown. However *preparing* the drawing, aka the *frame setup* is a valid step to parallelize. It always boils down to generate a linear list of objects to draw in order to maximize throughput and generate a correct result.

Of course the actual generation steps depend on the structure used. But for a multithreaded design it usually boils down to a *map and reduce* kind of approach.  Creating and synchronizing threads has a certain overhead. Luckily those problems are addressed by systems like *OpenMP*. I also suggest you perform the frame setup phase during the SwapBuffers wait of the preceding frame.

Comment: Well I don't have SwapBuffers as I do it all offscreen with custom FBOs ,but I got your point.Thanks!